# TypeScript syntax highlighting seems broken in this question

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67221976/why-cant-typescript-infer-the-return-type-of-this-function) in my feed and noticed that despite the code being nominally correct, the syntax highlighting appears broken, starting at the generic type parameters to the arrow function.

I copy/pasted it into Vim, Visual Studio Code, and [WebStorm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#WebStorm) and syntax highlighting worked correctly in all three.

Comment: Interestingly, that code block is being treated as lang-js, despite highlight.js having TypeScript support. I can't force it to use TypeScript highlighting here no matter what.

Comment: @BoltClock - btw, "Code Language (used for syntax highlighting): lang-js", maybe this has something to do with the issue. Highlighting seems to choke on generic type parameters syntax and does indeed generate a `lang-js` markup even if a fenced code block is used with explicit annotation `lang-ts`.

Comment: @OlegValter I've never followed up as to *why* [[tag:typescript]] has its syntax highlighter set to `lang-js`. Is there a story behind that?

Comment: @zcoop98 - frankly speaking, I am not sure either. Something tells me this is about the previous formatted used, but the MSE discussion is so huge that I can't bring myself to read it through. I became a bit active in TS recently, so I share the pain of `lang-js` screwing things up :) Fun fact: GitHub's formatter screws up highlighting for string template literal types

Comment: @Oleg Did some quick digging, I just discovered [this answer from @animuson♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354679/please-default-to-typescript-formatting-for-typescript-posts/354695#354695) on MSE that seems to lend some detail.

Comment: @zcoop98 but that answer is about questions tagged with both Javascript and Typescript, and that one is only tagged ts. Or did I miss something?

Comment: @JaredSmith - that's true, I don't get why the official syntax highlighting for TS in the wiki shows up as `lang-ts` if that's the only problem...  zcoop98 - thanks anyway, I've found myself too tired of endless posts to look things up :(

Comment: @JaredSmith You're right, it doesn't really apply in this case, I was more after some general context. On the one hand, this case is normal because it's getting highlighted as JS via the TS highlighter association, but on the other, it's really weird because using `lang-ts` explicitly still doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @Oleg Valter: lang-ts seems to choke on certain constructs. Generally it does work even when type parameters are present, but not in this specific case. It could be something else. Frustratingly, a *different* issue I had *just the night before this question was asked* was the comments in the second code block [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27982922/latest-on-css-parent-selector/27983098#27983098) not highlighting correctly despite the code block being correctly identified as lang-css.

Comment: @BoltClock - I meant that `lang-js` chokes on type parameters :) Because when the explicit lang annotation is not overridden, the markup is generated as expected (`pre class="lang-ts typescript"`) whereas the markup generated in the question Jared linked it is not (`pre class="lang-js javascript"`). So I think that's the crux of the issue. Re: css - wow, judging from the markup, it can't parse the selectors, but I don't get why

Comment: @BoltClock - an additional note on the highlighter breaking on generic type parameters is that it cannot properly chew default types in those parameters (writing a wiki for the related tag proves to be quite a chore because of that) no matter what

Comment: FWIW I think this is a bug in highlight.js - I've seen it in a few other contexts. I've raised an [issue](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues/3276).